# Adobe Acrobat JavaScript

Tags: javascript, adobe, acrobat

I'm a graphic designer working on an order confirmation form with Adobe Acrobat. I know nothing of Javascript but I managed to write a formula to calculate the price of items on the pdf.

Now I'd like to fix one last thing, if I don't want the number to show up when it is less than 0 what should I do?

the script right now is pretty simple:

```js
event.value = ( this.getField("fill_1").value * this.getField("Prezzo € x kg Prezzo € x foglioRow1").value )
```

Fill_1 and Prezzo € x kg Prezzo € x foglioRow1 are the names of the cells.

Is there any online tool to help me figure this out? do you have any advice?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kNPKw.png)

Answer (score 0):

It's a matter of a simple condition. Does this work?

```
var x = ( this.getField("fill_1").value * this.getField("Prezzo € x kg Prezzo € x foglioRow1").value );
event.value = x < 0 ? "" : x;
```

If the line above didn't work then I'm stumped.
I would the followings:

- what event is that?
- does it have more relevant code?
- did you mean `x <= 0`?
- what happens if `event.value = 12`?
- what happens if `event.value = 'hello'`?
- what happens if `event.value = this.getField("Prezzo € x kg Prezzo € x foglioRow1").value`?

Comment: No :( it doesn't, do you think is possible that Acrobat doesn't allow this kind of operation?